# Understanding Proof of Darboux-Weinstein theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

[Here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Ejeffrey/mat1312/lec13.darboux.pdf) is the version of proof that I am trying to understand, along Moser’s method.

Towards the end of 2nd page we find $\omega _t$ restricted to $N$ being non degenerate, which is fine. What I am unable to understand is the very next line stating that this implies $\omega _t$ on a neighborhood of $N$ too is non degenerate for all $t$. Is this something trivial as in is it a property of differential forms (if so how)? Or is it a corollary of tubular neighborhood theorem (which I am not very familiar with)?

Answer (score 5):

This is mostly point-set topology. Because this is a local discussion I will work in a chart $\Bbb R^{2n} \hookrightarrow M$. The set $N$ is not important: what we will show is that if $\omega_p$ is nondegenerate then so is $\omega_q$ for $q$ sufficiently near $p$. That is, the set of $p$ for which $\omega_p$ is nondegenerate is open. Since $\omega_p$ is nondegenerate for all $p \in N$, the set of $p$ for which it's nondegenerate is an open set containing $N$ as desired.

The point is that $\omega$ gives a smooth map $\Bbb R^{2n} \to \Lambda^2(\Bbb R^{2n})$ sending $p \mapsto \omega_p$. Then there is a smooth map $\Lambda^2(\Bbb R^{2n})^* \to \Lambda^{2n}(\Bbb R^{2n})^* \cong \Bbb R$, where this map is $\omega \mapsto \omega^n$ and the last isomorphism is the determinant.

$\omega_p$ is nondegenerate if and only if $\det \omega^n \neq 0$. Because $p \mapsto \det \omega^n_p$ is continuous, and $\Bbb R \setminus 0$ is open, it follows that $$\{p \mid \omega_p \text{ is nondegenerate}\}$$ is open.

Comment: Could you please explain how this map $\Lambda^2(\Bbb R^{2n})^* \to \Lambda^{2n}(\Bbb R^{2n})^* \cong \Bbb R$ is continuous? If I understand this correct, this maps essentially says that there is a mapping between 2-form and $\Bbb R$, where this implicitly means that a 2-form eat 2 tangent vectors to produce this mapping, and the 2 tangent vectors need not be associated with the point $p$ right? Differential forms are smooth just means that the first map $\Bbb R^{2n} \to \Lambda^k (\Bbb R^{2n})$ is smooth right?